# Open CSV file and writing each row to new, dynamically named CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with, say, 50 rows of data, and I would like to split it into separate csv files for each row, which includes first row (header) and the the relevant row.

E.g.
file 1 contains: row1, row2,
file 2 contains: row1, row3,
file 3 contains: row1, row4

And so on.

Currently working with:

```
import csv

counter = 1

with open('mock_data.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        filename = "file_%s" % str(counter)
        with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile_out:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out)
            writer.writerow(row)
            counter = counter + 1
```

I'm currently getting 'csvfile_out' not defined.

a) Am I even approaching this correctly
b) Any ideas why csvfile_out isn't being defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this and it works fine for your purpose. Unfortunately, I didn't get any `csvfile_out error` and your **with statement** works correctly in my Python 2.7.12 console.

```
import csv

counter = 1

with open('mock_data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    row1 = next(reader) # here you save your first line of the .csv file
    for row in reader:
        if row: # if row is not empty, write a file with this row
            filename = "file_%s" % str(counter)
            with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile_out:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile_out)
                writer.writerow(row1) #here you write your row1 as first row of csvfile_out
                writer.writerow(row)
                counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The undefined error was me being stupid. Which is good, because I definitely didn't think there was anything wrong with the code!

Comment: Follow up: I'm having a weird issue with this. The `writer.writerow(row)` is being put onto the 3rd row with a blank row between. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that this issue can come up if you have blank rows in your 'mock_data.csv'. You have to remove blank rows from your 'mock_data.csv', [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521426/delete-blank-rows-from-csv) , or check in your code if a row is blank or not (I put this second option in my answer, I hope that can fix your issue).

Comment: Turns out I actually forgot to add `newline=''` to `with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile_out:` - adding that removed the blank row.

Truthfully, I don't know why that is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `pandas`. Assume the content of csv as follows:

```
Name, Age, Gender
John, 20, Male
Jack, 22, Male
Jill, 18, Female
```

And my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("mock_data.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    file_name = row['Name']+".csv"  #Change the column name accordingly
    pd.DataFrame(row).T.to_csv(file_name, index=None)
```

This will create filenames based on the values of the column "Name" (i.e. Jack, John and Jill) to produce three files `John.csv`, `Jack.csv` and `Jill.csv`. Content of `John.csv` is as follows:

```
Name    | Age   |  Gender |
---------------------------
John    | 20    |  Male   |
```

Content of `Jack.csv` is as follows:

```
Name    | Age   |  Gender |
---------------------------
Jack    | 22    |  Male   |
```

Content of `Jill.csv` is as follows:

```
Name    | Age   |  Gender |
---------------------------
Jill    | 20    |  Female   |
```

***P.S:*** If you don't want the header, just add `header = None` when calling `.to_csv()` function. For example:

```
pd.DataFrame(row).T.to_csv(file_name, index=None, Header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DictReader too...

```
import csv

counter = 1

with open('mock_data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        filename = "file_%s" % str(counter)
        with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile_out:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
        headers = dict((n, n) for n in reader.fieldnames)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerow(row)
        counter = counter + 1
```