# Saving csv files dynamically with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 3 datasets which need to be read and then do some calculation on some columns and makes a new columns, finally I have to save new columns in a new csv file. I do not know how to do it dynamically as in each iteration I need to save with different name. For example the following code does not work.

```
df.to_csv("./dataset/file'+i+'.csv',index=False)
```

and i is the iteration number in my loop.

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: Does this work? `df.to_csv("./dataset/file'+str(i)+'.csv',index=False) ` ?

Comment: @AlterNative Mode should be `w`... else pass the filename to `to_csv` and pandas will create it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43953288/2888239) to a similar problem,

Here is a solution with `pandas`. Assume the content of csv as follows:

```
Name, Age, Gender
John, 20, Male
Jack, 22, Male
Jill, 18, Female
```

And my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("mock_data.csv")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    file_name = row['Name']+".csv"  #Change the column name accordingly
    pd.DataFrame(row).T.to_csv(file_name, index=None)
```

This will create filenames based on the values of the column "Name" (i.e. Jack, John and Jill) to produce three files `John.csv`, `Jack.csv` and `Jill.csv`. Content of `John.csv` is as follows:

```
Name    | Age   |  Gender |
---------------------------
John    | 20    |  Male   |
```

Content of `Jack.csv` is as follows:

```
Name    | Age   |  Gender |
---------------------------
Jack    | 22    |  Male   |
```

Content of `Jill.csv` is as follows:

```
Name    | Age   |  Gender |
---------------------------
Jill    | 20    |  Female   |
```

***P.S:*** If you don't want the header, just add `header = None` when calling `.to_csv()` function. For example:

```
pd.DataFrame(row).T.to_csv(file_name, index=None, Header=None)
```

The hint is to use `file_name` as a variable generated from any of your columns or input before (or while) passing to the `to_csv()` function.