# How to get the updated csv file after deleting blank rows?

Tags: python, csv

I have csv file with many entire blank rows.

Step 1: I follow the first answer in this link [Delete blank rows from CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521426/delete-blank-rows-from-csv) to get rid of the blank rows. The code in this link is

```
with open(in_fnam) as in_file:
    with open(out_fnam, 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        for row in csv.reader(in_file):
            if row:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

My csv file name is `"Profit.csv"`. I wrote my code like this

```
with open("Profit.csv") as in_file:
    with open("Profit_1.csv", 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        for row in csv.reader(in_file):
            if row:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Step 2: I then checked the missing values and blank rows in `"Profit_1.csv"` but they are the same as the missing values and blank rows in `"Profit.csv"`

QUESTION: What should I do now to get the updated csv file after deleting blank rows? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete blank rows from CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521426/delete-blank-rows-from-csv)

Comment: No. I read the answer in this link already. I believe this helps deletes blank rows in the original csv file but I don't know to get the updated csv file (the one with blank rows).

Comment: In the first answer in the link, there is a line `with open(out_fnam, 'w') as out_file` which I believe writes the output to a file named by the variable `out_fnam`. Have you checked whether any new file is getting saved?

Comment: I've checked several times but out_fnam have the same missing values as in_fnam. It seems they are the same file or may be I did something wrong.

Comment: I see. If you edit the question and add in what you have tried, and also add the modified/whole code that you are using, someone may be able to help you better :)

Comment: Here I understood that in_fnam is my ``FileName.csv" (my original csv file). I wrote out_fnam as ``FileName_1.csv". Then, I checked missing values of ``FileName_1.csv" but they have the same missing values as the original csv file, i.e. ``FileName.csv".

Comment: @pmcarpan Thanks! I do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty row in a CSV file will result in a `row` object that is a list of many empty strings (`['','','','','']`). In this case, `if row:` returns `True`.

Change

```
if row:
```

to

```
if any(row):
```

in order to remove rows that consist solely of empty strings.

Comment: I've just done so but then all missing values are gone. But all values becomes "NaN" and all columns' names become "Unnamed:0, Unnamed:1, ect"

Comment: Ah, of course, my solution was bass-ackwards... please try again

Comment: Also, don't forget to use the correct method for opening CSV files (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)). i. e. use the `newline=''` parameter - otherwise you can expect problems with CSV files that contain embedded newlines.

Comment: Thanks so much, Tim. I believe the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Ithink you need to close the file between step 1 and 2

Comment: I modified the question a little bit. Could you please take a look my question again and give me a comment? Thanks!